# NoSuchMethodErro:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.copyTableJobPropertiesToConf

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Every Hi:

There is a exception i have never encountered,Pls see the below:

```scala
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.copyTableJobPropertiesToConf(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/plan/TableDesc;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$.initializeLocalJobConfFunc(TableReader.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader.$anonfun$createOldHadoopRDD$1(TableReader.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader.$anonfun$createOldHadoopRDD$1$adapted(TableReader.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.$anonfun$getJobConf$8(HadoopRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.$anonfun$getJobConf$8$adapted(HadoopRDD.scala:181)
```

What's the code is:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object test {
    def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "nuochengze")
        val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Test")
                .master("local[*]")
                .config("hadoop.home.dir", "hdfs://pc001:8082/user/hive/warehouse")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate()
        spark.sql("use test")
        spark.sql(
            """
              |select * from emp
              |""".stripMargin).show

        spark.close()
    }
}
```

A thing that made me at a loss happended when i used spark to operate hive：

I can perform DDL operations through spark.sql(...).But when i try perform DML operations,such as select ,the above Exception will be reported,I know the lock of this method.But after searching the internet,i did not find any related blogs that if this method is missing,how can solve it?

Have you encountered it? if ture, can i ask for help?

Thinks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the error. Due to my negligence, when importing modules into pom.xml, there are some inconsistencies between the versions of some modules. If you encounter similar errors, you can refer to my current maven configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```